# Can any expression be written in terms of the natural exponent?

Tags: exponential-function

Let's start off with a simple function say $y = x$. Can it be written in terms of the natural logarithm? If so, are there any functions that cannot?

Comment: Does $\ln y = \ln x$ count?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question?

Comment: Of course, this only works as long as both $x$ and $y$ are greater than $0$.

Comment: @JohnNash That is not rigorous, as you assume x and y are both larger than 0 without expressing it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$ we have that

$$y=x \iff y=\ln e^x$$

and more in general

$$y=f(x) \iff y=\ln e^{f(x)}$$

Otherwise if we are interested in a $\log-\log$ identity

$$y=f(x) \implies \ln y = \ln (f(x))$$

is true only for $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Although this is cheating, as by log rules we get $y = f(x) \ln e $

Comment: And obviously $\ln e$ is $1$.

Comment: @WilliamGrannis Yes indeed it is an identity!

Comment: @WilliamGrannis I've added also the case for the log-log expression.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of functions which cannot.  For example, consider [Ackermann's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).  It can be rigorously shown that $A(x)$ is not expressible in any way save recursively.  You could add an $\ln$ to the definition, but it would still not be expressible in closed form.

Comment: I'm not sure what "it can be rigorously shown that $A(x)$ is not expressible in any way save recursively" means. It's true that the Ackermann function isn't primitive recursive, but I don't see why that implies what you've written.